# PHP MySQL effectively get place by Lat Lng

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, geolocation

I'm building PHP application on MySQL which should receive array of coordinates and should return from places table places around.

My approach is to calculate rectangle around point, so I have N,S,W,E limit coordinate. This is not a problem but there are like tons of duplicate's which I have to somehow remove.
So I thought about make array of fetched ids and exclude them from query.

```
$fetchedIds =[];
    foreach($json->points as $point){
        $Pqb = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Places')->createQueryBuilder('p');
        $query = $Pqb->where(
            $Pqb->expr()->between(
                'p.latitude',':NB',':SB'
            )
        )
        ->andWhere(
            $Pqb->expr()->between(
                'p.longitude',':WB',':EB'
            )
        )
        ->andWhere(
            $Pqb->expr()->notIn(
                'p.id',':fetchedIds'
            )
        )
        ->setParameter('NB', $point[1])
        ->setParameter('SB', $point[0])
        ->setParameter('WB', $point[3])
        ->setParameter('EB', $point[2])
        ->setParameter('fetchedIds', $fetchedIds)
        ->getQuery();

        foreach ($query->execute() as $place) {
            $fetchedIds[] = $place->getId();
        }

    }
```

Thing is notIn makes this query not getting any result even id it is empty array.

I'm missing something and I don't know what.
Also can you thing of another approach which would be faster?

**//EDIT 1:**

well this faster takes around 36ms in 10k fields, but I still think that this could be faster, in some other way.

```
$POSqb = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:places')->createQueryBuilder('pos');
    $or = $POSqb->expr()->orX();

    foreach($json->points as $point){
        $or->add(
            $POSqb->expr()->andX(
                $POSqb->expr()->between(
                    'pos.latitude',$point[1],$point[0]
                ),
                $POSqb->expr()->between(
                    'pos.longitude',$point[3],$point[2]
                )
            )
        );
    }

    $query = $POSqb->where($or)->getQuery();
```

Comment: Why don't you remove the duplicates on the database query level? "Group BY" OR "Distinct" ?

Comment: I would have to create single query for all 20-40 points. Duplicates are not in one query but in many together.

Comment: In my opinion, you are better off having a complex query and not having to remove duplicates manually in your code. For example, if you're doing offset/limit (pagination), it can get rather complicated to do that in the code while removing duplicates. All you would need then is to make multiple "OR between" filters for each coordinate pair.

Comment: I agree but pagination is really simple in MySQL. In this case you suggesting that I should call 40 selects and on it make group by. I didn't fin way how to do it in doctrine

Comment: But you will not be able to paginate using MYSQL, if you are removing duplicates in the code - because how are you going to paginate the results of multiple queries and merge it into 1? And also, what will you do with ordering? or is it not relevant?

Comment: I don't want to paginate, you were talking about it. There is no pagination and never will be.